# running shell scripts in different directories

Tags: bash, shell

I have  a directory named `tinkering` which has following subdirectories:

```
saraswati\ and\ durga\ pooja
64\ yogini\ pooja
52\ guruwar\ ke\ tap\ se\ unemployment\ finish
bajrang\ bali\ har\ lete\ ain\ devote\ dukh
bhoot\ bhagane\ ke\ tareke
bacho\ ko\ gussa\ ane\ ka\ karan
durga\ pooja
khatre\ ke\ nishan\ hanth\ mein
saraswati\ and\ durga\ pooja
seb\ chadhane\ se\ ma\ hinnamasta
bhoot\ bhagane\ ke\ tareke
```

Each of these sub directories has a script named `script.sh`.

I wrote a script on the **terminal**:

```
cd ~/tinkering/; 
cd saraswati\ and\ durga\ pooja/;  
./script.sh;    
cd ..;  
cd 64\ yogini\ pooja/;  
./script.sh;cd ../;  
cd 52\ guruwar\ ke\ tap\ se\ unemployment\ finish/;  
./script.sh;cd ../;  
cd bajrang\ bali\ har\ lete\ ain\ devote\ dukh/;  
./script.sh;cd ../;  
cd bhoot\ bhagane\ ke\ tareke/;  
./script.sh;cd ..;  
cd bacho\ ko\ gussa\ ane\ ka\ karan/;  
./script.sh;cd ..;  
cd durga\ pooja/;./script.sh;  
cd ..;  
cd khatre\ ke\ nishan\ hanth\ mein/;./script.sh;  
cd ..;cd saraswati\ and\ durga\ pooja/;  
./script.sh;cd ..;  
cd seb\ chadhane\ se\ ma\ hinnamasta/;  
./script.sh;cd ..;  
cd bhoot\ bhagane\ ke\ tareke/;  
./script.sh;cd ..;
```

But this script could not run. The purpose was rather than going to each subdirectory and typing `./script.sh` I be able to automate this process. What mistake did I do in the code above?

**EDIT** 
Please note I wrote these commands on terminal separated by a semi colon while I was in parent directory tinkering all the subdirectories have a different script which is doing a  different work I want to invoke all the shell scripts of sub directories from parent directory on terminal.

Comment: We don't know what "could not run" means.

Comment: Absolutely. I've gone with the assumption that it's missing the shebang or not executable, but that could potentially not be it.

Comment: Also another thing on design: Are all of these `script.sh` files the same, and it's just a matter of which directory you run it from, or are they doing different things?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan by design script.sh do same thing but all these scripts are in sub directories of tinkering I am at the directory tinkering, but when I write cd in a shell script the directory does not changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for subdir in */; do
  cd "$subdir"
  ./script.sh
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: A decent start, but the addition of a few characters can eliminate the need for the `cd ..`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: are you meaning doing it as `(cd "$subdir"; ./script.sh)`?

Comment: Yeah, wrap `cd $subdir; ./script`-part in a parentheses to subshell it. No need to cd "out of it".

Comment: @Roland Illig yes you caught the correct thing I wanted to know how can I change directories in shell script the directories are having blank spaces in their names and in my script the cd command is unable to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have pointed out, "could not run" could mean a number of things. E.g. if you get a message saying `Permission denied`, you have to use `chmod a+x script.sh` if you want to invoke your script with `./script.sh`.

If you're able to run your scripts with `/some path with whitespace/script.sh`, you could put this into a shell script under `~/tinkering/`.

```
find -name script.sh -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -exec sh {} \;
```

Comment: @flesh no it is not about permissions the script in parent directory is not able to change directories which are mentioned by cd command

Answer (score 0):

The script needs to be executable and have a shebang.

Put `#!/bin/sh` on at the start and run in the terminal `chmod +x myscript.sh` (for whatever you've called your script).

If you're trying to do all subdirectories, you could also do it more efficiently with a `for` loop (I see Roland has provided the answer for that so I'll omit it).

Comment: Unless you pass the script to the interpreter yourself, e.g. `bash somescript.sh`.

Comment: True, but with what he's saying about running `./script.sh`, I think it most likely he's not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might work .

```
for d in */; do
 cp scr.sh "$d"
 chmod +x scr.sh
 done

for subdir in */; do
  cd "$subdir"
  ./scr.sh
  cd ..
done

for d in */; do rm scr.sh "$d"; done
```